# Laravel – перебор внутри контроллера с привязкой к модели

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь вывести информацию из базы данных и привязать к ней изображения – хочу следовать шаблону mvc.

```
// Контроллер 
$events = Event::where('show_or_not', '=', 'show')
   ->get();

// А здесь мне нужно подцепить картинку для каждого id из перебора
foreach ($events as $event) {
   if (file_exists(public_path( 'img/'.$event->id.'.jpg' ))) {
      $img = '<img src="public_path( img/'.$event->id.'.jpg )">'
   }
}
```

Как все это сделать правильно? Возможно нужно прописать как функцию в модели? И как потом выводить в представлении?

Comment: Если именно такой вариант, то безусловно это нужно делать в шаблоне.

Comment: Единственное конечно можно сделать 2 функции hasImg и getSrc

Comment: Рендерить html элемент из модели неправильно. При просмотре кода шаблона не будет понятно, что там в методе скрыто. А лезть в модель, чтобы добавить класс к изображению - это даже как-то грустно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге сделал через функцию в модели. Спасибо всем за обсуждение.

```
// Контроллер
$events = Event::where('show_or_not', '=', 'show')
   ->get();

// Модель
public function eventImage() {
   $img = '<img src="public_path( img/'.$this->id.'.jpg )">';
   return $img;
}

// Представление
@foreach ($events as $event)
   {{ $event->eventTitle }}
   {{ $event->eventImage() }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: очень грустно. А можно взглянуть на весь код целиком, который касается данного вопроса?

Comment: @newbie собственно вся суть изложена выше.